# videoinput with C#

Tags: c#, video-capture

I have a video capture (usb-webcam) application that currently uses very old VFW with p-Invoke hookup to C#.  I'm trying to replace it and I stumbled on the [VideoInput library](http://muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/), and later found [VideoInputSharp](http://code.google.com/p/videoinputsharp/).  I managed to get [VideoInputSharp](http://code.google.com/p/videoinputsharp/) into my application and it gives me the frame rate and camera control I need.  The problem is that on some PCs the call to VideoInput.IsFrameNew() never returns true even though the device is set up (VideoInput.IsDeviceSetup() does return true).
I've successfully run this on a W7x64 system and a XPx32 system, but does not work on W7x32.  Any thoughts on why this is happening?

**UPDATE1:**
Since originally posting this question, I've found that on the systems that don't work, I am still able to call VI.ShowSettingsWindow() to generate a dialog box; however, it is a different dialog box than I see on the systems that work (even though it is the same camera/driver).  Is this a clue?  Also note that I'm running the same version of DirectX on the machine it works with and the machine it doesn't work with.

**UPDATE2:**
The systems that this is failing on are W7x32 and W7x64 both using a Microsoft LifeCam.  I found yesterday that if I remove the Microsoft LifeCam software from the machine it then works!  I sure could use an explanation for that.

Comment: What about the card's drivers for these systems?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand your question.  I'm working with a webcam, and the drivers are installed; and although the webcam can vary, in this case the same webcam is being used on the systems it works on and the systems it doesn't work on.

Comment: I see. You just didn't state that in the question, that's why I ask. And does the camera work on every system in some other applications?

Comment: Yes, it does.  My app currently allows me to hook to the camera with either VFW or VideoInput.  If I use VFW it works fine.

Comment: I've updated my original text a few times to make it more to the point and to also include new detail.